# JSEncrypt to PyCrypto RSA encryption not possible

Tags: python, python-2.7, rsa, pycrypto, jsencrypt

I'm trying to encrypt a string in Javascript using RSA (public key)
And I want to decrypt that string in Python (2.7) with my private key.

The Libraries I am using are [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) and PyCrypto
The Problem here is, that PyCrypto has problems to decrypt the encrypted string

This part encrypts the string:

```
var encrypted = new JSEncrypt();
encrypted.setPublicKey(key); // key == '-----BEGIN PUBLIC'.....
encrypted = encrypted.encrypt('test');
```

The produced encrypted String looks like this:
HJuyZtuUbR4EvjZp0pirbEw0OX8KD7UDNyvSMx3plfzYPjV7r8RBOkouCkvPBG2XOF6E5lPr0ukWClF0u5HB8M6qF8b9xTMnM/j5e41iaPa/oIZyL0JC4h+FZ7cv/P6ygmaSafQ1xc96JltTbuW3u/YYdwmv/01CnFyaIEWW3gk=

This part should decrypt it:

```
private_rsa_key = open('rsa_1024_priv.pem', 'r').read()
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(private_rsa_key)
decrypted = rsa_key.decrypt(b64decode(encrypted_string))
```

The result now should be 'test', but indeed it is:
[image]

The correct string is always being placed at the end, but i need to get rid of the part before it.

For testing purposes I tried encrypting the String in Python, using this code:

```
public_rsa_key = open('rsa_1024_pub.pem', 'r').read()
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(public_rsa_key)
encrypted = rsa_key.encrypt('test', 'x')
```

which perfectly turns out 'test' when decrypting, but looks quite different encrypted:

```
('\x0bY\x1ckk\x7f\xd6\xda$\x05g\xa0\x0bxI\x0cO9\x8b?>M#X\xd2_[\xb7\xf1\xd0f\xb4\x92C\x01z\xa4\x02q\xb9\xb1\x80\x82\xe8\xe4\\E\x85\xa7r\xff\x1aIL,\xd8\xce\xaf\xef\xb4)\x84\x92]\xabA\xc9+\xd6\xef}\x08\xce\xe8\x97\xf8}\x84(\xb3\x9c\xfe7g\xe0\x869\x8b\xe8\xf8\xdf\x85}\xb0\x87\x1a2\xab\xda\xca\xfd\x81\xc0\x98\x12y\x92\x13\xd6\xa5a\xf3\x9aU\xb5\xa4d\xb8\xfc\xa3\xd1\xe2<\x07\xda\xc3\x9e\xc2',)
```

I am wondering why this encrypted text is now a tuple, with hex inside. As in my opinion the encrypted string from JS looks correct. How could I get PyCrypto to correctly decrypt the string?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python code you posted only does the low level decryption, the encrypted data returned by the jsencrypt also [contains pkcs1 padding](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/9e43644e5448e57c584004e8548b594dc9be6db7/bin/jsencrypt.js#L1354).

Instead of using the raw RSA key to encrypt/decrypt in your python code, you need to use the appropriate [cipher](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher-module.html), in this case [PKCS1_v1_5](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html):

```
...
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
private_rsa_key = open('rsa_1024_priv.pem', 'r').read()
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(private_rsa_key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted, "ERROR")
```

The same applies when encrypting with the public key.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I had to change the last row to:  decrypted = cipher.decrypt(b64decode(encrypted), "ERROR")   and it works now.

Comment: Yea, this snipplet assumes that `encrypted` is really the raw encrypted data, as would be produced using e.g. `cipher.encrypt(b'some message')`. I think such a case may be more common in general, so I'll leave the answer like that, base64 en/decoding if needed is trivial.